# A Net::SMTPAuthenticationError occurred in messages#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, google-apps

I'm getting errors sending e-mails from my Rails app using Google, which goes:

```
A Net::SMTPAuthenticationError occurred in messages#create
454 4.7.0 Cannot authenticate due to temporary system problem. Try again later. ch3sm7566201qab.9
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:966:in `check_auth_response'
```

This is my `setup_mail.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,             
  :domain               => 'oursite.com',
  :user_name            => 'support@oursite.com',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto =>  true
}
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: :user_name should be gmail and same as password to it. Try to login from gmail.com website. If it opens, username and password mismatch. :user_name should be 'yourusername@gmail.com'

Comment: @vajapravin Those details are correct. Thanks!

Comment: add this ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

Answer (score 0):

I had this some problem from Python, and simply logging into the gmail account online fixed it.